# Is it safe to rapidly toggle fan speeds?

Tags: linux, cpu, desktop, fan, dell-inspiron

I'm trying to run a large computation on my Dell Inspiron 620 desktop, making the CPU generate a lot of heat. Unfortunately, [the resulting fan noise](https://andrewsun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dell-inspiron-fan-noise.mp3) can be quite frightening, especially at night!

It turns out that this computer has exactly two speeds for the CPU fan - low (~500 RPM), and very loud (~3000 RPM). I've been playing with fancontrol trying to make the fan noise more bearable. I wrote this bash one-liner to work around this limitation:

```bash
while true; do echo 191 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm1; sleep 0.35; echo 192 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm1; sleep 0.36; done
```

Running this script seems to make the fan spin at an appropriate speed. Is it safe to run this script for extended periods of time, switching the PWM value between "slow" and "fast" 3 times per second? Will it wear out the fan motor or other components? Are there other, less hacky ways to make the fan run at a speed that sufficiently cools the CPU without waking me up at night?

Comment: Get a watercooler like the corsair h100 it is quiet, and is a complete kit.

Comment: I have the 120mm chassis fan in my home server plugged into the +5V line instead of the +12V line

Comment: have you tried speedfan? if it works for your hardware, it is quite useful for monitoring temperatures, speeds, and power.

Comment: @FrankThomas SpeedFan cannot control the fans in my computer (I've tried) and I primarily use Linux, which SpeedFan does not run on.

Comment: Are you going to be using it at night or not?

Comment: Also, Siri on macOS toggles fan speeds. It turns it off when the microphone is used and turns it back on. Try ~3 seconds of `sleep` instead of 0.35, and go lower every day/test.

Answer (score 1):

The fan has one moving part there is no wear mechanism related to changing its speed.

getting an intermediate speed by this trick seems likely to be benign or even beneficial in every scenario I can think of.